# Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id XXX

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

Disclaimer, I'm still a very newbie, so I really need your help.

At first I was created a telegram bot that works to search/find a data in a spreadsheet based on its name. Everything went well, until the spreadsheet I was using now had a row of 50,000++, now my bot didn't run like before. And when I check my code, there is this error:

`Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id XXX`

Here's my function to fetch/get all the data in the sheet:

```
function GetAllData(){
  var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Cell = mySpreadsheet.getRange("A3:AB"+ raw_live.getLastRow());
  var Cell_contents = Cell.getValues();
  return Cell_contents;
}
```

And here's my function to find the data by it's name:

```
function SearchAttributebyName(ID){
  var attribute = GetAllData(); 
  for (var row=0; row<attribute.length; row++) {
    if(attribute[row][0]==ID){ 
      return "xxxxxxx"
    }
  }
    return "xxxxx";
}
```

Can anyone please help me, how can I get the data without getting the error/expection?

Comment: Is this Google issue tracker related to your situation? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156530211

Comment: Yes, it is simillar, but still I couldn't get the answer for my problem. sleep of flush, i don't understand them. If they can solve my probblem, can you help me how I use them on my code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you show seems fine, and although it could be improved a bit, I do not think that would help with the performance issue you describe.

Chances are that the bad performance is caused by the *spreadsheet* rather than the script. To improve spreadsheet performance, see these [optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).